# Error message in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

What does "??? Undefined function or method 'lowpass3d' for input arguments of type 'int16'." really mean? Do I need to change the format of the input argumant?

Thanks for any helpful answers.

Comment: It might mean that `lowpass3d` was never designed to take arguments of type `int16` as input. maybe it takes `double`, maybe not. what is `lowpass3d`?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is that you don't have a function named `lowpass3d` in MATLAB's search path.  The other possibility is that `lowpass3d` doesn't accept an integer argument, though this is much less likely.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the existence of a function called `lowpass3d` by running:

```
which -all lowpass3d
```